# Algorithm for laying out a directed acyclic graph in memory to maxmise data locality

Tags: algorithm, graph, directed-graph, directed-acyclic-graphs

Say I have the edges

```
A -> C
A -> D
A -> E
B -> D
B -> E
```

To maximise data locality I'd arrange for the DAG to be stored in this order in memory (as an array) to minimise the distance between the node and it's dependencies.

```
C, A, D, E, B
```

so that A has a distance 1 to C, 1 to D, 2 to E.

And that B has a distance of 1 to E, and 2 to D.

Is there name for an algorithm that does this? If not, how would one implement this?

Comment: `C, A, D, E, B` only ordered points is this the only thing you keep in memory ? then how you store the direction attribute ? as per your storage `B` has a distance of 3 to `A` but `B` is not directionally connected with `A` it goes like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting. Lemme look again

Comment: There is another list that stores the edges. I only listed the nodes since the edges weren't that relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want to linearize the DAG. I don't know whether you are using it for dependancy resolution. [`Topological_sorting`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) looks familiar to your question. also the program [`tsort`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsort_%28Unix%29) does very similer thing.

However it is dependancy linearization.

```
neel@gentoo:~$ tsort
C A
D A
E A
D B
E B

C
D
E
B
A
```

Which prints the order in which that tasks have to be performed. and it will possible not work if there is a cycle. its relevant as you mentioned its acyclic.

I dont know if there is any such algorithm for `data locality ordering string` or anything similar however It looks like your data locality string have some problem.

What if `C` is close(1) to `A` and is also close(1) to `B` and `B` is too far(4) from `A` how will you represent it with your data locality string ?

I don't now what exactly you want to do. If you want to liniarize dependency to perform tasks in proper order then do a topological sort.

Comment: I suppose I'd optimise data locality for the node with the highest degree. Obviously there will be ambiguities, but I think with data locality a close-enough mentality should be adopted. As long as the overall distance is minimised.

Comment: `node with more edges` are you sorting by degree of a vertex ?

Comment: `degree` of a vertex doesn't hold direction and connection with other vertexes and sorting by them may not retain dependency integrity. and in that case you will know which vertex is heavier. but the term `locality` doesn't fit with a sort by vertex degree

Comment: an out_degree doesn't tell you about locality.If its ordered by out_degrees I don't know How you get about how near it is with other nodes. so the term `locality with respect to other nodes` is not obeyed. with your `locality string` you want to store the whole DAG. and you want to extract the in informations like distance between two particular nodes. but there is even no way to understand whether two vertexes are connected or not. I've played with these things long ago. I may miss some terms.

Comment: Well I'm storing the edges in another list so that's not really my concern. The only thing I need is the ordering of nodes with a good data locality (there are a lot nodes and the cache is thrashing).

Comment: I think to achieve a "close enough" data locality, topological sort should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Here is slightly different approach to improve locality:

http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-733/paper_pacher.pdf

The described algorithm seems to be closer to [force-directed graph drawing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force-directed_graph_drawing) algorithm than to topological sorting.

You should also read papers on in-memory graph databases such as [imGraph](http://blog.euranova.eu/2013/08/imgraph-a-distributed-in-memory-graph-database/)